# Required request part 'config' is not present node-fetch

Tags: node.js, curl, node-fetch

I'm trying to convert this curl command to a node fetch request.

```
curl -X POST    http://localhost:7200/test    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'    -F "config=@test.ttl"
```

What I have so far sends the file as formdata via a POST request, just like the curl request. However, I am not sure how to include the `config=@test.ttl` in the request. I tried adding it to a headers object and I got back invalid characters errors so I am not sure where to put it. When I run the request the way it is below. I get back `'Required request part 'config' is not present'` so it is definitely required to put the `config` somewhere.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const FormData = require('form-data');
const form = new FormData();  
form.append('test.ttl', 1);

fetch('http://localhost:7200/test', { 
        method: 'POST', 
        body: form 
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `form.append('config', '@test.ttl')`

Comment: That didn't work. It still returned `Required request part 'config' is not present`

Comment: I'm trying variations of appending it onto the formdata, but they arent working. Is there maybe a specific header required to put it in?

Comment: `form.append('config', fs.createReadStream('test.ttl'));`

Comment: That worked thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@bato3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194525/bato3)!

Creating a readStream for the data in the file worked. Posting the working code below if anyone wants to reference it in the future.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();

form.append('config', fs.createReadStream('test.ttl'));

fetch('http://localhost:7200/test', { 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: form 
})
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```